# How to clean repeated words in columns of a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean my data to do some analysis. My data (`.csv`) are outputs of some experiment, so same format or words repeated in each column. I add an image of my original data. In each of my four columns I have::

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'rev45s':['Area is    389.62 km^2','aspArea is  76.61 km^2','asp_Ave_slip is  1.59 m','Mw is 5.5'],
                   'rev45':['Area is    589.32 km^2','aspArea is  66.65 km^2','asp_Ave_slip is  3.69 m','Mw is 6.1'],
                   'SS45':['Area is    319.62 km^2','aspArea is  61.71 km^2','asp_Ave_slip is  3.09 m','Mw is 6.8'],
                   'SS45s':['Area is    489.52 km^2','aspArea is  54.61 km^2','asp_Ave_slip is  1.44 m','Mw is 9.5']})
```

I need to make a new `Dataframe` with

- first column as "parameter"=(Area, aspArea, asp_Ave_slip, Mw )
- second to forth columns as
  "rev45s_value","rev45_value","SS45_value","SS45s_value"
  and the
- fifth column as "unit"=(km^2, km^2, m, -)

I tried some code like:

```
df['rev45s']=df['rev45s'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split()))
```

and

```
df['rev45s']=df['rev45s'].str.split(' ')
```

but they didn't work. How can I clean this DataFrame?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your sample data and expected output in the text of your question, not as a picture or link, to make a [mcve] according to [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: I think you should transpose your dataframe so you have [Moment, AverageSlip, asp-Ave_slip, ..., Mw] as column names. Then you can use `applymap(lambda x: x.split()[2])` to extract the numeric values

Comment: @G.Anderson thank you. I edited my question

Comment: Thank you for updating, however it would also help to see an example of your expected output based on this input, as your written description is not entirely clear

Comment: @G.Anderson I can answer if you ask me the unclear parts